# systemV to systemd executing a simple c program as a services but cannot find printf debugs on console

Tags: c, linux, service, raspberry-pi, systemd

Hi I am trying to write a systemd service to launch a simple hello world program at bootup. I am unable to see the simple printf statements on the /dev/ttymcx0 which is my terminal. Is there a way where i could let the systemd service to print to the terminal. when i run the status i can see that the service is running.

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello world service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
StandardOutput=journal+console
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/bin/helloworld.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my sample c application

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(void){
        while(1){
            printf("test print \n");
            usleep(3000);
            }
    return 0;
}
```

this is my shell script calling the c application

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/bin
helloworld
```

When i see the systemctl status helloworld I can the the service as running but it does not seem to print any debug messages to the terminal.

I can see the service running but do not see the printf printing messages to the console.

Comment: *＋1* for asking a question that has something to do with programming and development, and not just a systemd config dump.